# System.Text.Json.JsonException error message triggered when app is running

Tags: c#, docker, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I am having an issues with my asp.net core web api application. I am using docker-compose to use elasticsearch and kibana to read logs. I do not get any errors when I build the program. However, once I hit the run button it gives me System.Text.Json.JsonException error message and it is on the line

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```

But the line it says it is on is a blank line. Could I be looking at the incorrect line? Not sure where the line is missing what it is saying because when I try to click on it, nothing happens.

`Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ElasticSearchLogs
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                        .WriteTo.Console()
                        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(node: new Uri(context.Configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
                        {
                            IndexFormat = $"{context.Configuration["ApplicationName"]}-logs-{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
                            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                            NumberOfShards = 2,
                            NumberOfReplicas = 1
                        })
                        .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

`WeatherForecastController.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ElasticSearchLogs.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var rng = new Random();
                
                if (rng.Next(0, 5) < 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Oops what happened??");
                }

                return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Something bad happened");
                return new StatusCodeResult(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ApplicationName":  "elastic-search-app",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  }
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Missing comma before allowed hosts. You could have spotted this with any online JSON validator.

Comment: Wow, I did not catch that! Really? I never knew about this, appreciate it for sharing this with me!

Comment: To be fair the error message also told you where to look and what you did wrong. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing a comma in the configuration json

```
{
  "ApplicationName":  "elastic-search-app",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```